# ElasticSearch Nest MatchPhrasePrefix Multiple Fields

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to use Nest C# and link to an textbox for searching. I have multiple fields that I would like to search on but I cant get it working right.

This works for me if I am searching one field [Title] for the partial text of "tit" to match something with the value of "title" , but I have 2 more fields I want to add to the search as well.

```
var searchResponse = client.Search<Search>(s => s
  .Query(q => q.MatchPhrasePrefix(m => m.Field(f=>f.Title).Query("tit").MaxExpansions(10)))
  .Index("myindex")
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [multi match phrase prefix query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#multi-match-types)

```
client.Search<Search>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .MultiMatch(mm => mm
            .Fields(f => f
                .Field(ff => ff.Title)
                .Field(ff => ff.Message)
                .Field(ff => ff.Description)
            )
            .Type(TextQueryType.PhrasePrefix)
            .Query("tit")
            .MaxExpansions(10)
        )
    )
);
```